# StringCchCat for concatenating integers with strings in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, string-concatenation, strcat

I want to concatenate integer with string like this:

My code snippet is like this.

```
TCHAR dest[MAX_PATH];
int i = 2;
StringCchCopy(dest,MAX_PATH,"Begining_");
StringCchCat(dest,MAX_PATH,LPCTSTR(i));
```

The last line is causing an exception. I know the last line is wrong. 
"Begining" & the concatenated string should be "Begining_2". How do I achieve this in C++ ?

Comment: What is `STRSAFE_LPCTSTR`?

Comment: By using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). Or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: syntax of StringCchCat needs LPCTSTR

Comment: You need to convert i to a string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix for your code:

```
TCHAR dest[MAX_PATH];
int i = 2;
_stprintf_s(dest, MAX_PATH, _T("Begining_%d"), i);
```

As you can see I've simplified it and made it more secure. So there is no need to use `StringCchCopy`/`StringCchCat` functions.

Please note that the way you doing it is pure C, in C++ on Windows platform it should be done like this:

**Using MFC framework (UNICODE compliant):**

```
int i = 2;
CString sDest;
sDest.Format(_T("Begining_%d"), i);
```

The `CString` does have `(LPCTSTR)` cast operator. So you can use it directly in any function that accepts `LPCTSTR` type of parameter.

**standard C++ way (UNICODE compliant):**

```
int i = 2;
std::wstring dest(L"Begining_");
dest += std::to_wstring(i);
LPCWSTR str = dest.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
int i = 2;
std::wstring ext = std::to_wstring(i);  // convert integer to wstring
StringCchCat(dest, MAX_PATH, ext.c_str()); // pass wstring here
```